# PHP: get_called_class() returns unexpected value

Tags: php, static, self

Using PHP 5.3+ and having something equal to the following I get the output of 'C' instead of 'B':

```
class A
{
    public static function doSomething()
    {
        echo get_called_class();
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public static function doMore()
    {
        self::doSomething();
    }
}

class C extends B {}

C::doMore();
```

If I had used static::doSomething() that would be the expected result, but when using self::doSomething() I expect this method to get called in the scope of B because it's where the 'self' is defined and not the late static binding.

How is that explained and how do I get 'B' in the doSomething() method?

Thanks in advance, JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is [late static binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php).  The `get_called_class()` function will use late static binding to return the class name, `__CLASS__` will use late static binding if called using `static::`, but not when used with `$this->` or `self::`.  I don't know of a way to get it to return `B` short of having the echo within `B` instead of `A`.  It sounds like this would be an ideal use of traits if you were using PHP 5.4.

Example:

```
class A
{   
    public static function doSomething()
    {   
        echo __CLASS__;
    }
}

class B extends A
{   
    public static function doMore()
    {   
        self::doSomething();
    }
}

class C extends B {}

C::doMore();
```

This returns `A` instead of `C`.

Answer (score 1):

Override the method doSomething, to get `B`

```
class C extends B
{
    public static function doMore()
    {
        B::doMore();
    }
}
```

**`Tested`**

Comment: Using parent doesn't resolve the problem as get_called_class() still returns 'C', but I need 'B' in that case. Even using B::doSomething gives me a 'C' as output.

Comment: J.S. I just tested on PHP 5.4. Its returning `C`

Comment: Thanks for testing, that's what I expected. But I need 'B' in that place, what can I use instead of get_called_class to achieve that (except fiddling with the backtrace)?